# How do I change the innermost nested statements, but keep the outer statements?

Tags: java

This is a bit of a confusing question so I'll do my best in asking it.

Say I have a bunch of code before and after a specific code block. The code surrounding the code block always stays the same but the code inside the block can change. For simplicity, consider that the surround code is a doubly nested for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
    for(int i = 0; i<height; i++){

        // changing code block

    }
}
```

Now, I want to tell the compiler to insert different bits of code into the code block at different instances in my program. How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: *at different instances in my program* - What do you mean?

Comment: @MarounMaroun probably means that the behavior contained inside the `for` loop can change dynamically, and `interface`s solve this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How do interfaces solve this? The code within the interface is overridden in any derived class.

Comment: You can use inner classes if they need to access to the state of the class where the method that contains these two `for` loops resides. If you want to get a more precise answer, provide more info about your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have to declare an interface with a method and send an object reference of a class that implements the interface that holds the logic to implement. Basic code example:

```
interface Foo {
    public void doFoo(int i, int j);
}

class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public void doFoo(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println(i + j);
    }
}

class Baz implements Foo {
    @Override
    public void doFoo(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println(i - j);
    }
}
```

In your current code block:

```
public void doXxx(Foo foo) {
    //...
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<width; j++){
            // changing code block
            //solved using interfaces
            foo.doFoo(i, j);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Now you can call `doXxx` using an implementation of `Foo`, like an instance of `Bar` or `Baz`:

```
doXxx(new Bar());
doXxx(new Baz());
```

Comment: Ugh. I hate polymorphism. I guess this is one way to solve the problem.

Comment: You may hate polymorphism, but this is the most elegant and accepted way to do it in Java.  When Java supports closures it will be a bit prettier, but will still rely on polymorphism.

In Javascript, you'd pass in a function, in C you'd pass in a function pointer.  It all achieves the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I would use external services to run the needed code, and use IOC (or whatever you like) in order to configure the proper service for each instance.

```
private MyService myService;

for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){

        myService.myMethod();

    }
}
```

And use:

```
public interface MyService {
    public void myMethod();
}

public class MySimpleService {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        // Do whatever...
    }
}

public class MyOtherService {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        // Do whatever...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other Languages might solve this using closures.. For Java you need to pass an object of a class.

For e.g, you might have a function called `Looper`, and it takes a param `operation` and you would call the function with this operation.

To do this in pre-java 8, what you can do is write a function that takes an object which is say callable or something equivalent and perform your thing.

(Probably has minor errors, forgive me, been a while since I wrote Java code, hope the idea is clear)

```
public interface Operation {
    public int performOperation(int a, int b);

}
...
public void Looper(Operation o, int a, int b){
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
        for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
             o.performOperation(a,b);
        }
    }


}



 //elsewhere

   Looper(new Operation{
       public int performOperation(int a, int b){
            return a + b;
       }

    }, 10,15);
```

This pattern is seen in `map`, and other similar functions in functional languages, `foreach` and a million other functions in  in C++.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was the most understandable. Luiggi has pretty much the same idea but he replied first so I'm going to make his answer the solution. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @BigDru You are most welcome, you can upvote all 3 answers as well, to show that it solves your question whoAmi 's answer is the same concept as well.

Comment: I only have 10 rep so I actually can't upvote yet. If you upvote my question that will bring me to 15 and I can upvote all three.

Answer (score 0):

You can put [if condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) or [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) or any conditional statement inside the block.

To execute separate code logic.

**Just example:**

```
for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){

        // changing code block
        if(codition1){
        //Execute block1 logic
        }
        else if(codition2)
        {
         //Execute block2 logic
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that something like this would work but it would have to be in its own separate method that would need to take an int as a parameter. Then I could use the switch statement to test the parameter for the correct code that needs to be run.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this in to he wrong way. If you want to simply swap out code, create a static method and call it:

```
for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){

    m1();

}
}

for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){

    m2();

}
}
```

and make the methods as:

```
static void m1(){
    //something
}

static void m2(){
    //something else
}
```

Comment: You're still writing the for loops twice. I only want to write them once. Also, I used the for loops as an example. What if i needed the outer nested statements (the for loops) to be 150 lines long.

Answer (score -1):

Change it as

```
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<width; j++){
```

Comment: How does this answer anything?

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer. Removed my downvote since other answers fall in the same problem, shame on them.